# Is there an adjective that indicates two letters are used in the same word?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

The context for this question is word games like Scrabble, but it seems like it might also have minor applications elsewhere. If I played "book" and "solid" we could say that S and D have this quality, because they are used in the same word, but S and K do not, because they are used in different words.

Stuck in my head is "co-literal", but I'm fairly certain it's a neologism.

Comment: You might be able to refer to them as _co-linear_ (normally a math term referring to points that are "lying along the same [straight] line")....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "common". In your example, S and D are common to solid but not book. S and K are not common to either word.

From https://www.google.com/search?q=common+definition:

> shared by, coming from, or done by more than one. 
>  "the two republics'common border"
>
> belonging to, open to, or affecting the whole of a community or the public.
>   "common land" 
>    synonyms:  collective, communal, community, public, popular, general; shared, combined
>   "the common good"
>   antonyms: individual, private
>   Mathematics
>   belonging to two or more quantities.